# Display Name com Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

Tenho esse caso no meu projeto?

```
public enum TipoValorCalculoComissao
{
    [Display(Name = "Percentual")]
    Percentual = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    Valor = 2
}
```

E gostaria de colocar esses valores em um combo, porem aplicando o Name ao invés da descrição do enum.
Porem a unica maneira que consegui efetuar isso foi criar uma classe dessa maneira:

```
public class TipoValorCalculoComissaoView
{
    public int Valor { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

E chamar dessa maneira:

```
private void ObterTipoValorCalculoComissao()
    {
        ViewBag.TipoValorCalculoComissao = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoValorCalculoComissao)).Cast<TipoValorCalculoComissao>()
                                                               .Select(v => new TipoValorCalculoComissaoView
                                                               {
                                                                   Nome = v.ToString(),
                                                                   Valor = (int)v
                                                               }).ToList();
    }
```

Porem dessa maneira não pego o Name do objeto, alguém conhece algum meio de pegar o Name do objeto para exibição via razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
public static string GetDescription(this System.Enum en)
{
    Type type = en.GetType();

    MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

    if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        var attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            return ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
        }
    }

    return en.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Bom dia Rodolpho eu fiz uma função semelhante e acabou funcionando, mas a questão é...
O Name já é um DataAnnotations, se eu passo tudo para o view, porque o Razor não consegue pegar esse atributo do objeto de uma maneira mais simples...

Comment: Porque quando você esta chamando o ToString(), ele esta chamando o método que vem desde a classe Object, que normalmente mostra o nome da classe\tipo. Por isso você precisa dizer explicitamente que você quer ler a propriedade `name` do atributo em questão. Até porque, o mesmo objeto pode conter diversos atributos relacionados.